# Wrap a problematic npm package, while maintaining type information

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

## The Problem

We're authoring an npm package containing React components that will be used in various (internal) web sites. There is a problematic npm package dependency that we are forced to use in our react .tsx files, that has these problems:

1. It doesn't expose any useful types despite having `.d.ts` files in it... they're empty.
2. It tries to run when required or imported server-side, instead of waiting until called, so we have to avoid a top-level import and instead do `if (window) { const module = require('package-name') }` and then use it inside that block only.
3. It is a frequent source of errors so everything in that library needs to be run inside of a `try ... catch` block.

## Well, At Least We Have Types

We have already created our own types file which addressed problem #1:

```js
// problematic-package-types.d.ts

declare module 'problematic-package' {
  function doErrorProneButNecessaryThing(
    foo: Record<string, unknown>,
    bar: string
  ): void
}
```

## The Needed Solution

The long term solution is to fix this problematic library and we're looking into how to get that done (but it's not in our direct control).

In the short term, though, we need a solution now.

Note that we are configuring dynamic requires in our npm package bundler to import them only at use-time, not treating them like other imports/requires. As our package is consumed inside other applications, we don't have full control over how that application bundling works or when the components are required, so our components may end up being required server-side when they shouldn't, and we have to tolerate that. We're still learning about some aspects of this.

## My Wild (But Failed) Stab

My goal is to do something more DRY like this, where we solve all three problems of strong typing, detecting server-side execution & doing nothing, and adding error handling:

```js
// hoping to leverage our module declaration above without importing anything
import type * as ProblematicPackage from 'problematic-package'
import wrapProblematicRequire from '../utils/my-sanity-preserving-module'
const wrappedProblematicPackage = wrapProblematicRequire<ProblematicPackage>()

// then later...

const foo: Record<string, unknown> = { property1: 'yes', property2: false }
const bar = 'yodeling'

wrappedProblematicPackage.invokeIfWindowReady(
  'doErrorProneButNecessaryThing',
   foo,
   bar
)
```

However, TypeScript doesn't like the `import type` which unfortunately makes sense:

> Cannot use namespace 'ProblematicPackage' as a type.

## The Plea

How do I get the type information we've placed into `problematic-package-types.d.ts` to use as desired?

Or ANYTHING else. Honestly, I'm open to whatever, no matter how crude or hacky, so long as we get some clarity and reliability at call sites, with full type information as described. Suggestions/advice?

## Full Details

Here is the full implementation of the `wrapProblematicRequire` function. I haven't tested it. It's probably awful. I'm sure it could be far better but I don't have time to get this helper module super clean right now. (My attempt to handle function type information isn't quite right.)

```js
type Func = (...args: any[]) => any
type FunctionNames<T, TName extends keyof T> = T[TName] extends Func ? TName : never
type FunctionNamesOf<T> = FunctionNames<T, keyof T>

const wrapProblematicRequire = <T>(packageName: string) => ({
  invokeIfWindowReady<TName extends FunctionNamesOf<T>>(
    name: T[TName] extends Func ? TName : never,
    ...args: T[TName] extends Func ? Parameters<T[TName]> : never
  ): T[TName] extends Func ? ReturnType<T[TName]> : never {
    if (!window) {
      // @ts-ignore
      return undefined
    }
    try {
      // @ts-ignore
      return require(packageName)[name] as T[TName](...args)
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      // ToDo: Log errors
      // @ts-ignore
      return undefined
    }
  }
})

export default wrapProblematicRequire
```

P.S. `await import('problematic-package')` didn't seem to work. Yes, problems abound.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot use namespace 'ProblematicPackage' as a type.

Well, you *can* get the `typeof` that namespace, which seems to be what you want.

To test this, I setup the following:

```
// problem.js
export function doErrorProneButNecessaryThing(n) {
  return n;
}
export function doErrorProneButNecessaryThing2(s) {
  return s;
}

console.log('did side effect');
```

```
// problem.d.ts
export function doErrorProneButNecessaryThing(n: number): number;
export function doErrorProneButNecessaryThing2(s: string): string;
```

And now you can do:

```
import type * as ProblemNs from './problem';

type Problem = typeof ProblemNs;

// works
type A = Problem['doErrorProneButNecessaryThing'] // type A = (n: number) => number
```

---

Then the `wrapProblematicRequire` function just takes the name of the function as a generic, pulls the args for it, and pulls the return type.

```
const wrapProblematicRequire = <TName extends FunctionNamesOf<Problem>>(
  name: TName,
  ...args: Parameters<Problem[TName]>
): ReturnType<Problem[TName]> | undefined => {
  if (!window) return;

  const problem = require('./problem'); // type is any, but types are enforced above

  try {
    return problem[name](...args);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error!');
  }
};
```

Here `require('./problem')` returns the `any` type, but the generics keep everything key safe as long as `typeof ProblemNs` can be trusted.

Now to test that:

```
console.log('start');
const result: number = wrapProblematicRequire(
  'doErrorProneButNecessaryThing',
  123
);
console.log('end');
```

Which logs:

```
start
did side effect
end
```

Which seems to work!

[Codesandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pylveq?file=index.ts)

Comment: I would never have guessed that `typeof (NameSpace)` would work. I'll experiment with this. Thanks!